Why does this 0.31 ETH token swap involve over 5 WETH being moved around?
0xc9786f742ce200807dce747f8221b7f4a02c634e3e13d332fb338ce68b191dc2
This is a txn hash for a swap of 0.31 ETH for another token using Uniswap. Why is there over 5 WETH being moved (to the token deployer I believe?) during the transaction?
Is it to even out the LP?
Why does Dex Screener show this as a ~$1000 buy (0.31 ETH, makes sense) followed immediately by an ~$18,000 sell (the 5-ish WETH) by the same wallet address?
Sorry if this is obvious, I’m still trying to learn how to read Etherscan, and make sense of the Dex Screener bit.

I think this logic comes from _transfer function of token.
It will swap back when balance of token contract > 200_000. You can take a look at here :
https://etherscan.io/token/0x40e3d1a4b2c47d9aa61261f5606136ef73e28042#code line #350
Balance of token contract increased by charging service fee when you do swap. You can see that it charged ~565 on your swap

When balance of contract is over threshold balance (200_000), it will sell those back to market and gain ETH. This is treasury address: https://etherscan.io/address/0x42cab3696a60c6fc51381bb533797e4121e1f168
